# Is there a specific word (or concept) for "teleological belief"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I tentatively believe that some people have a (relatively) fixed psychological characteristic of being impartial, of trying to actively consider arguments from various sides; unlike some who approach belief almost competitively, in the sense that they (possibly subconsciously, unaware even to themselves) are guided much more by emotional comfort, preference or familiarity in rigidly selecting any propositions that support the belief they have or want to hold, and even trying to suppress evidence that contradicts their belief, or fabricate or exaggerate anything to support their belief.

I have tried to think of a word which encapsulates this entire phenomenon, and I think it might be "teleological belief". In common parlance, epistemic "putting the cart before the horse", or "twisting facts to suit theories".

It is the idea that people do not take a stance in relation to belief that is like a neutral referee, observing, but that belief is highly goal-oriented, it is pragmatic and supposed to serve an end and you choose the beliefs you want, while simultaneously being actually able to believe them. It could also be considered "volitional belief", or "preference-oriented belief".

It could also be called something like "belief selection", to try to emphasize that in this scenario belief is approached through preference, in the way that people choose a favourite color or a type of furniture that appeals to them.

Are there any other good concepts or words to encapsulate this phenomenon clearly and precisely?

Comment: "*Bias*" seems to be a simple and common word for ignoring objectivity in favour of already formed beliefs.

Comment: Also "close-mindedness", "confirmation bias", "echo chambered", "reinforcement theory" and synonyms. There is a lot of psychological literature on this, so don't go creating your own theory without reading the literature. "Teleological belief" sounds like a belief about teleology so it's not a good phrase. Try asking on [Psychology SE](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: An already formed belief might be called a *prejudice*.  If you picked apart that word and referred to its Latin roots you might get the idea of a judgement (or belief) previously decided (or formed).

Answer (score 0):

These are called *presuppositions*.

> **Presupposition**
> *noun*
> something that is assumed in advance or taken for granted:
> The conflict could have been avoided if the speakers had openly acknowledged the presuppositions that each of them brought to the discussion.
> -[Lexico](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/presupposition)

This is a neutral term used to describe the (often unstated) assumptions that people carry into their thinking processes.

For example, in creation-evolution debates, creationists might presuppose the conservation of matter and energy (the physical universe didn't spring out of nothing on its own) whereas evolutionists might presuppose a 'big bang' event that violates the conservation of matter and energy (the physical universe did spring out of nothing on its own). Creationists might invoke God as creator and evolutionists might invoke quantum fluctuation on a massive scale, or whatever (the details are not relevant to this answer).

In both cases, the presuppositions colour the analysis of any observations, and each side can accuse the other of smuggling their conclusions into their assumptions, something that your term "teleological belief" seems to describe.